# Does Atom, the text editor, require internet connection to run code?

Tags: atom-editor, offline

I'm new to Atom, so far I've gotten my way around downloading packages and I'm slowly figuring out the customization. But I've been wondering if Atom requires internet connection to run, for example, Java code or Python code or some other code? Basically, can it run codes offline? (of course after downloading the proper packages and setting that stuff up).

Comment: The answer is no, you don't need an internet connection. However, please be aware that this site is specifically for questions regarding programming

Comment: @Kai Thank you! And I'm sorry, that was my first question, I wasn't sure where to ask it. Should I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Atom does not require internet connection for editing code except when you want to install extensions.
As a suggestion you can use Visual Studio Code for your coding needs. It is arguably the best text editor plus it has a large ecosystem of extensions you can use.
Visit https://code.visualstudio.com to download.